# some confusion about LinkedBlockingQueue Source Code

Tags: java, java-8

in the source of LinkedBlockingQueue

```
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    // Note: convention in all put/take/etc is to preset local var
    // holding count negative to indicate failure unless set.
    int c = -1;
    Node<E> node = new Node<E>(e);
    final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
    final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
    putLock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        /*
         * Note that count is used in wait guard even though it is
         * not protected by lock. This works because count can
         * only decrease at this point (all other puts are shut
         * out by lock), and we (or some other waiting put) are
         * signalled if it ever changes from capacity. Similarly
         * for all other uses of count in other wait guards.
         */
        while (count.get() == capacity) {
            notFull.await();
        }
        enqueue(node);
        c = count.getAndIncrement();
        // #Question 1
        if (c + 1 < capacity)
            notFull.signal();
    } finally {
        putLock.unlock();
    }
    if (c == 0)
        signalNotEmpty();
}
```

I have two questions:

1 in what condition at #Question 1 can happan? why we call notFull.signal() in a put method after put one object in the queue.

2 why the signalNotEmpty should lock the takeLock before notEmpty.signal()

```
 private void signalNotEmpty() {
            final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
            takeLock.lock();
            try {
                notEmpty.signal();
            } finally {
                takeLock.unlock();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The condition is `true` if the queue is full. If I understand it correctly the `notFull.signal()` call is not really necessary in the current implementation of `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Since all locks and conditions are private, derived classes would not benefit of the call either. So I guess it is simply there for ensuring correctness of future extensions to the class.

2) Acquiring the `takeLock` is necessary to prevent other threads from emptying the queue while `notEmpty` is signalled.

Comment: thx...so we found some extra code in jdk source-code, I can hardly believer that.

Comment: You're right. I hope I haven't overlooked something.